# Does Julia have something equivalent to Ans (Matlab) or Last.value (R)

Tags: julia

Matlab and R both have variables that are automatically assigned to the  (Ans and Last.value respectively).

Is there an equivalent for Julia?

e.g.

```
function myBigSlowFunc()
    sleep(10)
    return(5)
end
myBigSlowFunc()
# Can I get the value that was returned without rerunning the function?
```

Comment: If you are at the repl you can use  `ans` (just like matlab)

Comment: Awesome. That works. (I was incorrectly trying "Ans" instead of "ans")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are at the repl you can use `ans` (just like matlab)