# Re-use result of last line Jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, wolfram-mathematica, julia, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter notebook, is there any way to re-use the output the line above, within a cell?

Coming from Mathematica, I often find it useful to write things commands which work on the output of the last line using `%`, here's a stupid example:

```
Integrate[f[x],x]
Limit[%,x->1] - Limit[%,x->0]
```

In general one can write `%%%` for 3rd-last output etc. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html

@nostradamus reminds me that underscore `_` is the output of the last cell, at least in Python. ([Get last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200020/get-last-answer) .) I didn't initially ask this, but would particularly like to be able to do this within a cell, so as to be able to execute multiple steps with one shift-enter.

I would also like to know if there's a way of doing either of these in Julia instead of Python.

Comment: Things I found which don't quite help: 

* How to print all outputs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835741/8187364

* A package which supports Out(n): https://github.com/jlapeyre/Symata.jl

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200020/get-last-answer). Possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. Am I correct in thinking that `_` always uses cell output, not the output of lines within a cell?

I will update my question a bit if that is OK...

Comment: I think you are correct, although I do not understand what you mean by "not the output of lines within a cell". Whereas `_` will use the previous output, you can reference to any output cell using `_x`, which is an abbreviation for `Out[x]`. Furthermore, `___` works as well (as `%%%` in Mathematica). See e.g. [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-data-science/9781491912126/ch01.html) "Input and Output History".

Answer (score 4):

In julia, `ans` stores the result of evaluating the last statement.

```
4*2
ans/2
```

You may also be interested in checking out the piping syntax

```
4*2 |>
sqrt
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have found`ans` (also here, I now see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192955/does-julia-have-something-equivalent-to-ans-matlab-or-last-value-r  ) but never thought to look for pipe.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  "_" and works generally in python environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else finds this with google, I just discovered a package that does roughly what I wanted, in Julia: [ChainRecursive.jl](https://github.com/bramtayl/ChainRecursive.jl) uses `it` as the magic word, like so:

```
julia> using ChainRecursive

julia> @chain for k=1:4
           k^2 + k^3
           print(" $k -> $it ")
       end

 1 -> 2  2 -> 12  3 -> 36  4 -> 80
```

There appears to be no performance lost by using this, as it is un-wrapped before compilation.